# Question marked as duplicate of duplicate

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53402819/python-thinks-my-variable-is-local-but-it-should-be-global) was just marked as a duplicate, which I don't question, but I noticed the question it was marked as a duplicate of is, in fact, itself a duplicate.

Is this still considered "good practice", or should the duplicate be moved to one of the underlying non-duplicate questions?

Comment: IMO... if the question has an answer, it's a valid dupe target. closed or otherwise. It's possible that question C isn't as good of a dupe for question A as it is for question B.

Comment: A missed meta-opportunity here: closing as a duplicate of a [duplicate]! (I can't find one, though.)

Comment: I love how this question about duplicates of duplicates is a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is fine; a question may be closed as a more broad subset of a duplicate but that doesn't mean that the duplicate is any less applicable to other questions.

If nothing else, it gives anyone interested in learning more a clear trail to follow.